# Deleting hundreds milion of rows in single MySQL query

Tags: mysql, linux, innodb

we have a project with a huge MySQL table *(MySQL version 5.7.35-0 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 using InnoDB)* table. By Huge I mean approximately 100M of rows 300GB.

I want to do some pruning there. This can be achieved by this SQL query:

```
DELETE FROM Commit WHERE current=0;
```

But this will lock up the database and I need to terminate the process by force. I have an index on column current. I can split up the query into chunks:

```
DELETE FROM Commit WHERE current=0 LIMIT 100;
```

If I am deleting 1 row it is done immediately if 100 it takes few milliseconds if 1000 it takes a second, if 10000 approximately a minute, and unproportionally more and more (not linearly).

Is there some smart way how to iterate this query again and again until there is no row with this condition left? And without locking up the server?

Or can I somehow modify the strategy of deleting to do it in one query?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how long does it take to do `CREATE TABLE new_commit AS SELECT * FROM commit WHERE current <> 0;`?

Comment: You can't do it, since deleting the record is going to lock the underlying table anyways.

Comment: @coyeb60297 I am now a bit locked to do this because for this we have no disk space. But recreation can be a great idea.

Comment: Batching is one way of doing it. I.e. deleting x amount of records in a sequence and repeat that sequence every 3 seconds or so. Another way (which should be way faster, is to create a temporary table that holds all the records you wish to keep, truncate the original, then re-insert the records from the temporary table into the original).

Comment: Iteration until none left -> [mysql_affected_rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/c-api/5.7/en/mysql-affected-rows.html) aka [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) until it is 0.

Comment: Danyan - The delete is avoided.

Comment: Pavol - if you ar locked due to disk space, kill it.  Then rethink how to do the task.  (Please state in the question how much disk space you have to spare, and what percentage of the table needs to be deleted.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are deleting *most* of the table (and you have enough spare disk space), copy the rows *to keep* into an new table and use `RENAME TABLE`.

Else, walk thru the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table 1K rows at a time, deleting whatever rows in that chunk need deleting.

More discussion of both techniques, plus others:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Yes, your first attempt led to a very long lock.

Yes, your second attempt took longer and longer.  (The cure in the link above is to "remember where you left off".)  Yes, non-linear, probably "quadratic" -- about 100M * 100M / 100, which equals a huge number.  (Caveat:  If the Optimizer actually uses the index, the situation may not be this dire.)

Do it in a single query -- No.  Why does that matter?  (Based on your answer to that question, I will explain why some alternative is "good enough".)